# Isotope expand/contract feature

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I'm working on an isotope - which I want to get as close to the mcdonald example as the pane expands and opens up.

http://www.mcdonalds.de/produkte/alle-produkte

http://jsfiddle.net/9zX6z/1/

I have a class that sets the height/width

```
$(".element-item").on("click", function() {
                that.highlightBlock($(this));

                $("#filter").click();
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already nailed the basics - setting the width and height for the "expanded"/"open" Isotope element via a CSS class `open`

```
<li class="product open">
```

and then trigger Isotope's [reLayout](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#relayout)-method.

The zooming of the product image is implemented via CSS transitions depending on the presence of said class:

```
.product-image {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.product.open .product-image {
    width: 308px;
    height: 308px;
}
```

But just blowing up the thumbnail image dimensions wouldn't look very nice: *Before* adding `open` to the Isotope element, we thus replace the thumbnail image's `src`-attribute with the URL to a bigger version of the product image. The latter is stored in the `data-src-large`-attribute of the image:

```
<img class="product-image" data-src-large="product_preview.png" src="product_thumbnail.png" data-src-standard="product_thumbnail.png">
```

The implementation on the McDonalds product page also adds a CSS-class `item-open` to the parent container within which the Isotope items are contained:

```
<ul id="isotope" class="isotope item-open">
    <li class="product open"> ...
    <li class="product"> ...
    ...
```

Based on this class, the opacity of all Isotope-items which do *not* have the `open` class assigned is reduced, again via CSS:

```
.item-open .product {
    opacity: 0.15;
}

.item-open .product.open {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**You can see CodePens fitting the code-snippets above here:** http://codepen.io/fk/pen/dGAzl/ (using Isotope v1) and http://codepen.io/fk/pen/ohLvF/ (using Isotope v2) - both a bit rough around the edges, but working in the latest Chrome.

Please note that I used spin.js to display the loading indicator, slightly changed the CSS class names and left out a bunch of markup, vendor prefixes and IE-specific filters as opposed to the original McDonalds product page to make things a bit easier to grasp (hopefully ;)) - everything else is almost a 1:1 copy.

Also note that the imagesLoaded-plugin that comes [bundled with Isotope v1](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#imagesloaded_plugin) has its [problems](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/14) and you'll be probably better off using the current [standalone version of the plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) if you want to use it to determine when the high resolution product image is loaded.

The jsFiddle JavaScript contains a few comments to help you around.
I hope combined with the answer here, this gives you a few pointers on how to move on from where you currently are.